# R function using a 'for' loop that returns a list with number of uppercase, lowercase and numeric values in a string

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I am trying to learn how to write a function 'f' that takes an input string 's' and returns a named list with 3 components (the number of [0, 9] digits, of small and capital letters in `s`).

My answer must include a 'for' loop and to check my answer, The output of `str(f3("123abA"))` is:

```
#    List of 3
#     $ num: num 3
#     $ l  : num 2
#     $ L  : num 1
```

I did find a way to do it, but without including a 'for' loop. I know it may seem trivial to some people, but I'm just starting out and still need to develop skills using loops in R :)

```
f3 <- function(s){
  number <- str_count(s, "[0-9]")
  lower <- str_count(s, "[a-z]")
  upper <- str_count(s, "[A-Z]")
  return(list(num = as.numeric(number), l = as.numeric(lower), L = as.numeric(upper)))
}
```

Do you have an idea to help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To expressly ask for a `for` loop when there are known vectorized solutions is not very R-like but here it goes.

```
f4 <- function(s){
  x <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(s), ""))
  number <- 0L
  lower <- 0L
  upper <- 0L
  not_valid <- 0L
  for(y in x){
    if("0" <= y & y <= "9"){
      number <- number + 1L
    } else if("A" <= y & y <= "Z"){
      upper <- upper + 1L
    } else if("a" <= y & y <= "z"){
      lower <- lower + 1L
    } else {
      not_valid <- not_valid + 1L
    }
  }
  if(not_valid){
    msg <- paste("There are", not_valid, "invalid characters in input string.")
    warning(msg)
  }
  list(
    number = number,
    lower = lower,
    upper = upper
  )
}

str(f4("123abA"))
#List of 3
# $ number: int 3
# $ lower : int 1
# $ upper : int 2
str(f4("123ab.A"))
#List of 3
# $ number: int 3
# $ lower : int 1
# $ upper : int 2
#Warning message:
#In f4("123ab.A") : There are 1 invalid characters in input string.
```

Answer (score 0):

That is quite a weird assignment, as your current solution is quite good and efficient.

This would be a less efficient answer, but is does have a for loop:

```
f3 <- function(x){
  y <- strsplit(x, "")[[1]]
  
  vec_number <- c()
  vec_lower <-  c()
  vec_upper <-  c()
  
  for(i in 1:length(y)){
    vec_number[i] <- grepl("[0-9]", y[i])
    vec_lower[i] <- grepl("[a-z]", y[i])
    vec_upper[i] <- grepl("[A-Z]", y[i])
  }
  return(list(num = sum(vec_number), l = sum(vec_lower), L = sum(vec_upper)))

}
```

```
> str(f3("123abA"))
List of 3
 $ num: int 3
 $ l  : int 2
 $ L  : int 1
```